# Binding joined table with DataGrid XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have two table which has one-to-many relationship:
table 1  : -userid(pk)  -name
table 2  : -ownid(pk)   -vehicletype   -model  -userid(fk)

I joined two table get the result as shown in the pic which contain duplicate result of userid and name.
[joined table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alsrh.jpg)

How can I display these data in XAML DataGrid or something else similar, so that that data can be shown without having duplicated userid and name.

Answer (score 0):

Use Grouping feature of CollectionView class.

Msdn Tutorial :

[How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Exploring MVVM: Grouping with the DataGrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/01/21/exploring-mvvm-grouping-with-the-datagrid.aspx)